# Selectively using * on scoreboard player commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I have a scoreboard objective called `Timers`. I want every element that has a score (not null) on that scoreboard to increase their value by one each tick.

What I mean by this is, I want the command below to run every tick, so that I don't have to increment scores individually.

```
scoreboard players add *[scores={Timers=..0..}] timers 1
```

But selector tags don't work with `*`. If I use `*` on its own, I will get extra scores that I don't want, for all players (fake or real) and all entities.

Basically, I want to set any score `x` to 0. When I do, it will start to increment by 1 each tick. But when I reset that score to null, I want that to stop.

I'm on Realms on 1.15.2.

Comment: That's an interesting question, but your answer will likely be "impossible". So the real question becomes: Why do you want this? Could you not use @e instead? That doesn't work with fake players, but I don't know any situation in which you would need to do something for all manually added fake players. Quite the opposite, it can easily break other datapacks that are active at the same time.

Comment: Wait, do you actually want to select fake players as well? Otherwise it's reasonably easy.